# Find Previous Month MTD (Month to Date) Calculation in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Assuming I have initial table of date and each order value of the date:

```
date_order  |gross_order|
|---------- |-----------|
|25 Nov     | 50        |
|27 Nov     |300        |
|26 Dec     | 400       |
|29 Dec     |300        |
|30 Dec     |100        |
```

So I use this query for calculating current MTD (cumulative gross order in a month from day 1 of certain month to certain date in that month),

```
select date_order, gross_order, sum(gross_order) OVER (PARTITION date_trunc(date_order,MONTH ORDER BY date_order) AS current_mtd
```

the result will be something like this:

```
|date_order |gross_order| current_mtd |
|---------- |-----------|-------------|
|25 Nov     | 50        | 50          |
|27 Nov     |300        |350          |
|26 Dec     | 400       |400          |
|29 Dec     |300        |700          |
|30 Dec     |100        |800          |
```

The idea is to also have value of previous month MTD value for all row in the date range, so in the 25 and 27 Nov, previous MTD value will be 0 because there are no prior gross order value. And in the 30 december row, the value will be sum of gross_order between 1 to 30 november, which give us 50 + 350 = 400

Expected result:

```
|date_order |gross_order| current_mtd | previous_mtd
|---------- |-----------|-------------|-------------|
|25 Nov     | 50        | 50          |0            |
|27 Nov     |300        |350          |0            |
|26 Dec     | 400       |400          |50           |
|29 Dec     |300        |700          |350         |
|30 Dec     |100        |800          |350         |
```

I'm kinda stuck as how to calculate the previous mtd value, is there any way to do it? Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What do you mean by "previous MTD" calculation?

Comment: Month to Date Calculation, or cumulative value in a month from date 1 to certain date in that month. I edit my title, but in case it's not clear I specifically explain what I'm trying to achieve in the post

Comment: The 400 doesn't make sense.  It should be 350 based on your explanation.

Comment: Applogize, you're right, I miscalculated it, it should have been 350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I understand the question, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
with t as (
      select date '2020-11-25' as date_order,  50  as gross_order union all
      select date '2020-11-27' as date_order, 300  as gross_order union all
      select date '2020-12-26' as date_order, 400 as gross_order union all
      select date '2020-12-29' as date_order, 300  as gross_order union all
      select date '2020-12-30' as date_order, 100  as gross_order 
     )
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.gross_order)
        from t t2
        where date_trunc(t2.date_order, month) = date_add(date_trunc(t.date_order, month), interval -1 month) and 
              extract(day from t2.date_order) <= extract(day from t.date_order)
       )
from t;
```

The subquery is matching rows from the previous month (the first condition) and then comparing the date (the second condition).

This works on the data you have supplied.

Comment: Wow that works perfectly, thank you very much!!! If you don't mind could you explain the logic behind the where filter in the correlated subquery?